# Correct syntax for NgIf using async pipe with multiple template variables?

Tags: angular

With Angular, we can subscribe to an Observable and assign the result of the async pipe to another variable by doing :

```
    *ngIf="(data$ | async) as data; else loading"
```

We can check multiple conditions :

```
    *ngIf="(data1$ | async) && (data2$ | async); else loading"
```

But what is the correct syntax to verify multiple conditions using Angular "as" Keyword ?

I tried :

```
    *ngIf="((data1$ | async) as data1) && ((data2$ | async) as data2); else loading"
```

But I have an issue :

> Parser Error: Unexpected token &&, expected identifier, keyword, or string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the *object-like* syntax.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{
  data1: data1$ | async,
  data2: data2$ | async
} as data">
  <div *ngIf="data.data1 && data.data2; else loading"> 
    <span>{{ data.data1 }}</span>
    <span>{{ data.data2 }}</span>
  </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading> ... </ng-template>
```

Or, even better, just create a new `Observable` which combines the other two.

```
data$ = combineLatest(data1$, data2$).pipe(map(([v1, v2]) => v1 && v2));
```

Than, just

```
<div *ngIf="data$ | async; else loading"> 
  ...
</div>
<ng-template #loading> ... </ng-template>
```

Comment: Great answer. However, this functionality should be supported out of the box using standard syntax. Filed Angular bug report: [ngIf with two async Pipes using local template variables: Parser Error: Missing expected )](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32240)

Comment: @ChristopherPeisert I think they'll close it, as they were waiting for Ivy before actually working on a totally new template syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ data1 :data$ | async, data2:data2$ | async} as data;">
<div *ngIf="data.data1 && data.data2; else loading">

  {{data.data1}}
  {{data.data2}}
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
    loading..........
 </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider **LppEdd** answer.

`combineLatest` is not a correct use case, cause it will emit a value if any of streams will emit a data.

Use a `forkJoin` instead. When you work with http (I suppose you request some remote data here) - it will emit a result value if all of included streams will complete.